# Rails 3 scope undefined method `includes_values`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My model has this scope

```
  scope :supported, order("name").collect {|m| m.name}.join(", ")
```

and it throws an error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `includes_values' for "blah, blahblah":String
```

I'm thinking that it's because I'm trying to return a string as an ActiveRecord object, thoughts on how to fix it? Actually I have this code already working in the view but thought it might be better in the model, maybe not?

**EDIT**
Moving it into a non-scope class method works

```
def supported
  order("name").collect {|m| m.name}.join(", ") 
end
```

Here's a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899765/activerecord-rails-3-scope-vs-class-method) that better clarifies the difference between `scope` vs. `self` class methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what are you trying to do exactly?, if you want to return a string, use class methods. if you want to define a chainable ARel scope, well i'd always recommend to use class methods too, but some prefer the "explicit" way via `scope`.

```
def self.supported
  order('name').to_a * ", "
end
```

Comment: I'm trying to return a string and I thought `scope` methods does just that but then I get the error.

Comment: no scopes are basically to prepare database queries. they are chainable, and will perform the query if you try to use array methods on them, but they expect always a ARel object in the definition, and will always return one on call.

Comment: In Rails 3, scopes can also be defined as class methods. The advantage being the return values from those methods need not be ARel objects.

Comment: Huh Rails API doc is confusing in this regards. Anyway, I had to wrap my code above as you suggested in a class method and it works. I couldn't use your exact code since I don't want to return the whole object as string, just the name attribute.