# How to apply sorting and pagination when accessing objects of current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, pagination, kaminari

I'm using Rails 3.2 and Kaminari for pagination. I'm using the same controller action (index) for rendering all articles and all articles of a specific user. My controller code looks like this:

```
  def index
    @articles = (params[:mine] == "true") ? current_user.articles : Article.search(params[:search], :page => params[:page])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @articles }
    end
  end
```

and in my Article model:

```
  def self.search(search, opts)
    if search.present?
      where("category LIKE ? OR article_type LIKE ?", "%#{search}%","%#{search}%").page(opts[:page]).per(25)
    else
      page(opts[:page]).per(25)
    end
  end
```

My problem is I do not know how to apply sorting and pagination when showing the current_user's articles. The code for sorting is not yet there by the way. With the current code, I'm having this error 'undefined method `current_page' for #Article' when accessing the index action with the mine parameter set to true.

So my question is how do you apply sorting and pagination when using `current_user.articles`? Sample code would really help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should replace your class method with a scope:

```
scope :search, lambda {|search, opts|
  if search.present?
    where("category LIKE ? OR article_type LIKE ?", "%#{search}%","%#{search}%").page(opts[:page]).per(25)
  else
    page(opts[:page]).per(25)
  end
}
```

Then:

```
source    = (params[:mine] == "true") ? current_user.articles : Article
@articles = source.search(params[:search], :page => params[:page])
```

Comment: thanks, but I have a question though, why scopes? Aren't they the same as class methods?

Comment: `scopes` are chainable, not class methods

Comment: Oh..I see. But I'm still a bit confused, how can you call the search method on an array of article objects (current_user.articles)? Sorry if it's a newbie question.

Comment: Look in console it's not an array it's an active record query or alike

Comment: Yup, I've checked current_user.articles.class and it really returns an array. But it works though, which is weird.

Comment: Apparently, class methods in Rails 3 no longer execute queries as long as an active record relation is returned, based on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899765/activerecord-rails-3-scope-vs-class-method.