# Where to place common logic with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have a model `Project` that appears in multiple controllers in an application I'm building as it appears on multiple pages. The `where` clause for this isn't complicated, per se, but I feel like it is too large to be repeated on every method requiring projects with these constraints.

My question is, where, if possible, does this common call for `Projects` go? In `.NET`, I'd have a `ProjectService` class with a method that would return all projects, and another that returned all projects that satisfied my conditions. I'm new to Rails so I'm struggling to see where this fits in?

Comment: Check out scopes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: Scopes on your Project model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use a class method or Scopes.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  # example for a scope
  scope :awkward_projects,where(awkward: true)

  # example for a class method.     
  def self.awkward_projects
    where(awkward: true)
  end

end
```

Its very safe to do what was once given in a SO answer. Read below and choose carefully.

Quoting an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899765/activerecord-rails-3-scope-vs-class-method)

"Generally, I use scope entries for simple one-liners to filter down my result set. However, if I'm doing anything complicated in a "scope" which may require detailed logic, lambdas, multiple lines, etc., I prefer to use a class method. And as you caught, if I need to return counts or anything like that, I use a class method."