# scopes should be in controller or model?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to ruby and rails development and have this question in mind. If i have a concern with scope created say latest_records which gives me latest data for a customer

Now what is the best practice to use scope in this situation. should scopes be in model or in controller?

I read some online articles and it talks about fat model and skinny controller and since scopes are do database related work then i am guessing they should be in model.

Any suggestions or thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

You guessed it right.
Scopes belong to model and needs active record classs object to work on.
Scopes are nothing but a `activerecord` query divided in parts and it helps look your query elegant and dry.
e.g.
If you want to get users with confirmed emails, you would:

```
User.where(confirmed: true)
```

But with scopes in your user model:

```
scope :confirmed, -> { where(confirmed: true) }
```

And you would simply:

```
User.confirmed
```

For more detailed please refer this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4870157/6548745)

Answer (score 1):

A scope could only be defined in a model so it would have to be on a model.