# why we need to go for Named scope or scope in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Instead of named scope or scope, we can write a class method.

ex:

```
def self.desc
  <code>
end
```

Why would we ever use a scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can certainly write class methods which work just like scopes.  They are also a bit of a holdover from Rails 2.x when we didn't have arel to play with.

To me scopes are a way of "defining" the model like the associations do.  Scopes make defining these things nicer and cleaner, and they generally go at the top so you can see the model at a glance.

I've found I tend to move towards class methods when I need to start passing in arguments.  Yeah, there's a way to do it, but really at that point you're starting to want a class method (especially if there are optional arguments, though I believe Ruby 1.9 goes some way toward fixing that)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the both approaches. But via method it's gonna be more readable when your code for scoping grows.

Comment: You might want to revisit this answer and edit it, and add some explanation. In its present form it makes no sense at all.

Comment: Judging form the question (where the author neglected even to format it) I assume it's quit enough.

Answer (score 1):

[named_scope is awesome, it makes your codes much more readable, you can also combine named_scope finders to do complex finders](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/14-love-named_scope)

[What's the significance of named scope in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919730/whats-the-significance-of-named-scope-in-rails)

Comment: You can combine class methods too if you're returning Arel::Relation objects (starting with Rails 3)